# innerHTML добавляет символы =""

Tags: javascript, dom

В одном из методов приложения используется следующий код:

```js
var tpl = document.createElement('template');
tpl.innerHTML = text;
```

Где `text` содержит следующее значение (в строковом виде):

```
<nf-form form-title="Тестовая форма">
    <nf-input>
        <nf-input-mask scale="2" max-year="2099" min-year="1899" mask="N" map-to-radix="[".", ","]" thousands-separator=" " min="-1000" max="1000"></nf-input-mask>
    </nf-input>
</nf-form>
```

После добавления `text`'а в качестве содержимого, тег `<template>` выглядит так:

```
<nf-form form-title="Тестовая форма">
    <nf-input>
        <nf-input-mask scale="2" max-year="2099" min-year="1899" mask="N" map-to-radix="[" .",="" ","]"="" thousands-separator=" " min="-1000" max="1000"></nf-input-mask>
    </nf-input>
</nf-form>
```

Как можно заметить, в содержимом template'а появились символы `=""`.

Хотелось бы узнать, из-за чего такое произошло, и как это можно предотвратить?

Comment: Где-то в этих кавычках проблема, пробуйте — `map-to-radix="[\".\", \",\"]"`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, мимо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> map-to-radix="[".", ","]"
> ```

Это неправильно. Если пишешь руками, меняй на

```
map-to-radix='[".", ","]'
```

а если программно то ты где-то экранирование посеял - должно получаться

```
map-to-radix="[&quot;.&quot;, &quot;,&quot;]"
```

Comment: Да, выставляется программно. С экранированием все в порядке. Выглядит также, как вы и описали.

Comment: @corocoto, очевидно, что нет.

Comment: хм... спасибо. пойду тогда еще раз продебажусь. может быть в процессе работы скрипта что-то меняется.